# What is a front page in drupal ($is_front)?

Tags: theming

Nice to know for drupal beginners:

What is a front page in drupal and particularly in which case is $is_front true ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$is_front` is set on any template from [`_template_preprocess_default_variables()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/_template_preprocess_default_variables/7) (itself called from [`template_preprocess()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess/7)). It uses the result of the [`drupal_is_front_page()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_is_front_page/7) function.

`drupal_is_front_page()` will returns TRUE, if the path of the current page matches the `site_frontpage` configuration variable. This variables can be set from the "*Site Information*" configuration page.

Usually there is only a single front page on a Drupal site. If you use the Variable translation module (part of the [Internationalization](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) project), then you could translate the `site_frontpage` configuration variable and have a different front page for each enabled language.

It may also be possible to have other module alter the value of the variables on each request to have multiple front pages. Additional module may also alter the value of `$is_front` in all or only a few specific templates. However, I cannot think of any useful use case for this, except torturing the template developer with inconsistency.

Answer (score 1):

**`drupal_is_front_page()`** - returns the bool value `true` if it's the front page.